How to change Vrapper colors?
On Vrapper, default search highlight color may contrast poorly with dark theme:

How to change colors used, like search highlight?

From https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/issues/879:
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Vrapper * > Color

